# Variables in LDAP search

Tags: python, ldap

I am writing a Python 3 script which has command line arguments and I'd like to use one of the parameters as a variable. Here is the declaration of the parameter:

```
parser.add_argument('-p', '--project', help='Project name', type=str, required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

I'd like to search for the project name in LDAP with this command (the cn=args.project is the relevant part):

```
conn.search("ou=Projects,dc=irf,dc=local", 2, "(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=args.project))")
```

But it doesn't work because the function just doesn't consider args.project as a variable, so it doesn't find the entry. I've already tried a lot of variations, including "& args.project &", but nothing worked.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Python won't automatically replace your variable unless you explicitly format the string. Try using the following code instead:

```
conn.search("ou=Projects,dc=irf,dc=local", 2, "(&(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn={args.project}))".format(**locals()))
```